# Context window length in OpenAI API Codex models

Tags: openai-api, gpt-3

Is the completion window length included in the context window length for OpenAI Codex models?

For `da-vinci`, the context window length is set to `4000` tokens.

From what I understand, as an example, if the prompt length is `3500` tokens, then the remaining `500` is for the completion. And there is no way use the whole `4000` token as the prompt.

I am pretty sure in my understanding, but it would be helpful to have it confirmed by someone knowledgeable.

Answer (score 0):

The context length for da-vinci is 4096 tokens. The prompt tokens and max_tokens for the response cannot be greater than the context length.

This is from the OpenAI API docs:

> The token count of your prompt plus max_tokens cannot exceed the model's context length. Most models have a context length of 2048 tokens (except for the newest models, which support 4096).

Ref: https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create